# AWS Groups and Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, identity-management

I created an IAM user in a group "A" to which only two policies are attached (S3fullaccess and snsfullaccess).
Also I created a role to create, start and stop EC2 instances.

My question is that if I assign this role to user in group A, will it be able to start new ec2 instance or not after switching role, as this user firstly is a part of group where only access to s3 and sns is allowed.

Thanks and Regards.

I tried to grant ec2 related role to a user in a group where only s3 and sns access is allowed.

Comment: By "assign this role to user in group A", do you mean that you gave the user or group an additional policy that allows the user to assume the EC2 instance role?

Answer (score 1):

> if I assign this role to user in group A, will it be able to start new ec2 instance or not after switching role

Yes, after the user assumes the role

> as this user firstly is a part of group where only access to s3 and sns is allowed.

No. When a user assumes the role, only the roles permissions are used and nothing else.

Comment: Exactly, all other user permissions are dropped when you assume a role, only the role's permissions take effect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082732/what-is-exactly-assume-a-role-in-aws#:~:text=Assuming%20a%20role%20means%20asking,session%22%20with%20that%20role.)